# How do I stop safari form submissions in a designMode="on" area

Tags: javascript, forms, safari

I'm trying to stop form submissions from working in an iframe with designMode set to on. For every browser except safari I can just observe mousedown on window, and stop it if it's a form element. In safari the only way I can get it to not submit is to put onSubmit="return false;" but I would like to find a more global solution like stopping the mousedown.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a testcase we can look at?  (Or file a bug on http://bugs.webkit.org )